# React-JS convert CSS-in-JS to CSS string

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

In a react project, the end user can generate CSS using a tool.

I found how to generate JS object and pass it to `style={}` attribute but I want to convert the generated JS object to CSS string, so I can save it and use it in other places.

I want to convert JSObject to CSS:

**JSObject [Sample - Input]**

```
JSObject: {
  lineHeight: 1,
  fontSize: 15,
  padding: 0,
  margin: 0,
  msBoxShadow: '0 0 1px 1px #000',
  MozBoxShadow: '0 0 1px 1px #000',
  OBoxShadow: '0 0 1px 1px #000',
  WebkitBoxShadow: '0 0 1px 1px #000',
  boxShadow: '0 0 1px 1px #000'
}
```

**Expected CSS [Sample - Output]**

```
.cssClass{
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    box-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0) 0px 0px 1px 1px;
}
```

Comment: check this https://github.com/aramk/CSSJSON

Comment: @monssef Thanks but I want to convert Javascript object that generated using CSS-in-JS or JSS libraries to normal css [not JSON]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a solution for my question and posting here for future searcher.

I made this simple function to convert JS object to CSS string:

```
export const JSToCSS = (JS) => {
    let cssString = "";
    for (let objectKey in JS) {
        cssString += objectKey.replace(/([A-Z])/g, (g) => `-${g[0].toLowerCase()}`) + ": " + JS[objectKey] + ";\n";
    }

    return cssString;
};
```

Comment: what about the prefixes ?

Comment: @monssef when using the simple function I made it will convert this `MozBoxShadow` to the css prefix `-moz-box-shadow` and this works perfectly on my project, thanks :)

Comment: I have made a codepen based on this
https://codepen.io/BerkeKaragoz/pen/xxWRYdY

Answer (score 1):

While the accepted answer is a great and simple solution to the problem, for completeness I would also want to suggest [the css NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css) and its `stringify` method that adds features that someone visiting this question may be interested in.